# Drawing dashed `\subseteq` symbol

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

I am trying to draw a dashed `\subseteq` symbol:

[image: dashed \subseteq]

(in contrast to `\not\subseteq` or `\varsubsetneq` and `\nsubseteq` from the [amsfonts](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts/doc/#amssymb.pdf) package) but having no success. Is there any known way to do this? Also [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) was not able to find that symbol.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you better explain what “dashed” means? Do you want something line `\not\subseteq`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually no, I mean something along the (dashed) lines of \dashedleftarrow or \dashedarrow.

Comment: Can you point to an approximated graphic representation of what you mean?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3319310/dashed%20subseteq.jpg

Comment: @JoãoMoura Why do you need this?

Comment: To reflect a special case of subset inclusion where only compatible instances according to some conditions are taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one just paints white lines over the existing `\subseteq` and calls it `\notsubseteq`.  As currently defined, it will not scale to other sizes.  If that is a primary issue, perhaps the OP will let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\stackMath
\def\notsubseteq{\mathrel{
  \stackinset{l}{0pt}{c}{}{\wrule[2pt]{5pt}{.5pt}}{
  \stackinset{l}{1.6pt}{c}{}{\wrule[-4pt]{.5pt}{10pt}}{
  \stackinset{l}{3.35pt}{c}{}{\wrule[-4pt]{.5pt}{10pt}}{
  \stackinset{l}{5.1pt}{c}{}{\wrule[-4pt]{.5pt}{10pt}}{
 \subseteq}}}}
}}
\newcommand\wrule[3][0pt]{\textcolor{white}{\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}
\[ A \subseteq B \]
\[ A \notsubseteq B \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version that tries to cut the symbol at perpendicular intervals.  I redefine the white to red in the last version to show the overlays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,graphicx}
\stackMath
\def\notsubseteq{\mathrel{
  \stackinset{l}{0pt}{c}{}{\wrule[2pt]{5pt}{.5pt}}{
  \stackinset{l}{1.6pt}{c}{}{\wrule[-10pt]{.5pt}{3pt}}{
  \stackinset{l}{0.5pt}{c}{1.5pt}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{45}{\wrule[2pt]{.5pt}{3pt}}}{
  \stackinset{l}{0.5pt}{c}{}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{-45}{\wrule[-5pt]{.5pt}{3pt}}}{
  \stackinset{l}{3.35pt}{c}{}{\wrule[-4pt]{.5pt}{10pt}}{
  \stackinset{l}{5.1pt}{c}{}{\wrule[-4pt]{.5pt}{10pt}}{
 \subseteq}}}}}}
}}
\newcommand\wrule[3][0pt]{\textcolor{white}{\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}
\[ A \subseteq B \]
\[ A \notsubseteq B \]
\renewcommand\wrule[3][0pt]{\textcolor{red}{\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}%
\[ A \notsubseteq B \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much for the help.